# Unable to implement CitrusPay SDK for iOS in swift based app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, payment-gateway, citrus-pay

I am done with integrating 'CitrusPay iOS SDK' in my swift based app, by following steps give at https://github.com/citruspay/citruspay-ios-sdk. However, I am unaware of further implementation steps. I also referred http://www.citruspay.com/DevelopersGuide/ios/iosReg.html.

Anybody can help me regarding how do I use classes and methods, also UI for doing so. Do I need to design the UI for CitrusPay?

I want CitrusPay to work on 'makePayment' button action.

And please don't give me links to those documents again, as I've been through  them.